# Menu link not working with angular $routeProvider and Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angularjs-routing

I'm having trouble working with Angular.js $routeProvider, I have a link on a menu in which will be mapped via the angular route and will later call an action in the Spring, but it does not work! Below are my files...

**snippet of menu.jsp**

```
<li>
    <a class="tooltip-tip ajax-load" href="#" title="Clientes"><i class="entypo-user"></i><span>Clientes</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="tooltip-tip2 ajax-load" href="#/customer" title="Novo Cliente"><i class="entypo-newspaper"></i><span>Novo Cliente</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('jooceboxCrm', ['ngRoute', 'service', 'customer', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

**customer.js**

```
var app = angular.module('customer', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    //Set CSFR Token 
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");

    console.log('Acesso a Configuração do RouteProvider.');
    $routeProvider.when('/customer', {
        templateUrl : '/viatge/auth/customer',
        controller : 'customerController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/customer'
    });
});

app.run([ '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.customer = [];
    console.log('app.run');
} ]);

app.controller([ 'customerController', function($scope) {
    console.log('customerController');
} ]);
```

### EDIT

I'am using Spring MVC and Tiles framework for rendering my pages. So my  value for template url points to a method in Spring MVC controller:

`templateUrl : '/viatge/auth/customer'`

```
@Controller
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class CustomerController {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CustomerController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    @RequestMapping("customer")
    public String customerScreen() {
        return "customer/newCustomer";
    }
}
```

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-routing-integration)

Comment: Define "but it does not work".

Comment: @MikkoViitala, only the URL is changed. `/viatge/auth/home#/customer`. But Google Chrome Debug and the server-side action is not called.

Comment: That's the problem. Here `templateUrl` should point to actual template, e.g. `'/customer.html'` and url should be just `#/customer`.